# RecordNotFound error in rails ecommerce app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am building an eCommerce app in rails which has two products Chairs and Bookcabinets, i have created two different controllers and models for chairs and bookcabinets, it all worked now i wanted the user to be able to add these products to a cart so i created a ordering system from scratch by watching a tutorial, it worked for chairs but when i add bookcabinets to shopping_cart model it gives me an error: `Couldn't find Chair with 'id'=`

**Server Log**

```
Started POST "/cart/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-26 14:16:43 +0530
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by OrderItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wGAl7gZGXipKt7EzzZT1LuBgn2k8KnlaPagp0cQ3l6pIkr6mx8MdJAuhgkY7EEttrHjTSSpcRjqe0qZ0a2hrAA==", "bookcabinet_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"40"}
  Chair Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "chairs".* FROM "chairs" WHERE "chairs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 106ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Chair with 'id'=):

app/models/shopping_cart.rb:20:in `add_item'
app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

**My Order_items_controller**

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @items = current_cart.order.items
  end

  def create
    current_cart.add_item(
      chair_id: params[:chair_id],
      bookcabinet_id: params[:bookcabinet_id],
      quantity: params[:quantity]
    )

    redirect_to cart_path
  end

  def destroy
    current_cart.remove_item(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to cart_path
  end

end
```

**My Order_controller**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @order = current_cart.order
    end
end
```

** My Order model**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items, class_name: 'OrderItem'
end
```

**My Order_item Model**

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :chair
    belongs_to :bookcabinet
end
```

**My Shopping_Cart Model**

```
class ShoppingCart

  delegate :sub_total, to: :order

  def initialize(token:)
    @token = token
  end

  def order
    @order ||= Order.find_or_create_by(token: @token) do |order|
      order.sub_total = 0
    end
  end

  def items_count
    order.items.sum(:quantity)
  end

  def add_item(chair_id:, bookcabinet_id:, quantity: 1)
    chair = Chair.find(chair_id),
    bookcabinet = Bookcabinet.find(bookcabinet_id)

    order_item = order.items.find_or_initialize_by(
      chair_id: chair_id,
      bookcabinet_id: bookcabinet_id
    )

    order_item.price = chair.price
    order_item.price = bookcabinet.price

    order_item.quantity = quantity

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      order_item.save
      update_sub_total!
    end
  end


  def remove_item(id:)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      order.items.destroy(id)
      update_sub_total!
    end
  end

  private

  def update_sub_total!
    order.sub_total = order.items.sum('quantity*price')
    order.save
  end

end
```

**My Create_order migration**

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name, null: false
      t.decimal :sub_total, precision: 15, scale: 2, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**my CreateOrderItems migration**

```
class CreateOrderItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :order_items do |t|
      t.belongs_to :order, null: false
      t.belongs_to :chair, null: false
      t.belongs_to :bookcabinet
      t.integer :quantity, null: false
      t.decimal :price, precision: 15, scale: 2, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end


  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
  get '/cart', to: 'order_items#index'
  resources :order_items, path: '/cart/items'
  get '/cart/checkout', to: 'orders#new', as: :checkout
  patch '/cart/checkout', to: 'orders#create'
```

**Add To Cart Form**

```
<div class="button my-2">
              <%= form_tag order_items_path do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :bookcabinet_id, @bookcabinet.id %>
        <%= number_field_tag :quantity, 1 %>

        <button type="submit" class="btn cart"><i class="d-inline fa fa-cart-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="d-inline">Add To Cart</p></button>
      <% end %>
```

**Updated Server Log**

```
Started POST "/cart/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-27 00:24:13 +0530
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by OrderItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gqwsV8Z/0p74Y8WPLMmfk9vmoSPCFpP+lAtVxxH3KSvWUzYYIFtbQRkAzM5yh5HS/wAzelr90LJW64joFUpGwg==", "bookcabinet_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"40"}
  Bookcabinet Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "bookcabinets".* FROM "bookcabinets" WHERE "bookcabinets"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Order Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."token" = ? LIMIT ?  [["token", "20897ec5db2636f5"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  OrderItem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ? AND "order_items"."chair_id" IS NULL AND "order_items"."bookcabinet_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["order_id", 4], ["bookcabinet_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  Bookcabinet Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "bookcabinets".* FROM "bookcabinets" WHERE "bookcabinets"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT SUM(quantity*price) FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 4]]
   (0.2ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/cart
Completed 302 Found in 557ms (ActiveRecord: 10.4ms)


Started GET "/cart" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-27 00:24:14 +0530
Processing by OrderItemsController#index as HTML
  Order Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."token" = ? LIMIT ?  [["token", "20897ec5db2636f5"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering order_items/index.html.erb within layouts/application
   (0.4ms)  SELECT SUM("order_items"."quantity") FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 4]]
  OrderItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 4]]
  Rendered order_items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.0ms)
  CACHE  (0.1ms)  SELECT SUM("order_items"."quantity") FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 4]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (22.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1313ms (Views: 1304.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

Comment: On which line that error triggered? Can update the question with server log?

Comment: @Pavan i have updated the question, please have a look

Comment: Ok, by looking at the `params` there is no `chair_id` being passed which explains the reason for the error. Are you using any form to submit the order? If so please update the question with the code

Comment: @Pavan yes i am using a simple form for that, i have added the for in the question now, please have a look

Comment: You need to set a `hidden_field_tag` for `chair_id` just like you set it for `bookcabinet_id`. Can you tell me on which view page is the form located. And also I cannot see where you have defined `@bookcabinet`. If there is any relevant code missing, please post it in the question

Comment: this form is located on the show page of bookcabinets, a slimier form is also there in the show page of chairs @Pavan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180781/discussion-between-pavan-and-that-dude).

Comment: Can you update the question with the bookcabinets controller code?

Comment: do you need to have a chair when you are adding a bookcabinet @Thatdude

Comment: no it's not compulsory @SumanthMadishetty

Comment: @Thatdude its throwning an error as you are searching for chair every time you call add_item method and you are not passing chair_id

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for chair item every time you call add_item method so its throwing an error as you are not passing chair id so you need to modify the method as below

```
def add_item(chair_id:, bookcabinet_id:, quantity: 1)
chair = Chair.find(chair_id) if chair_id
bookcabinet = Bookcabinet.find(bookcabinet_id) if bookcabinet_id

order_item = order.items.find_or_initialize_by(
  chair_id: chair_id,
  bookcabinet_id: bookcabinet_id
)

order_item.price = chair.price if chair
order_item.price = bookcabinet.price

order_item.quantity = quantity

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  order_item.save
  update_sub_total!
end
```

end

Please feel free to ask if there are any questions regarding the same

Comment: Hey @Sumanth Madishetty thanks for your answer, it actually make sense, but after applying your answer am getting another different error:
`NoMethodError (undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/models/shopping_cart.rb:29:in `add_item'
app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:8:in `create'`

Comment: updated my answer @Thatdude You need to check the same condition every where you use that chair record

Comment: hey @Sumanth Madishetty thank you very much, it worked but i don't know why, when am adding either of the two products, the cart is coming as empty, nothing is getting added, i have updated my question with a current log, please have a look.

Comment: @Thatdude Can you place a debugger like binging.pry where you are accesing the products fot the cart

Comment: @Thatdude Please check through console if Order with that token and Order item with order id exist in database

Comment: strange but it's saying that the id=undefined
`Parameters: {"id"=>"undefined"}
  Chair Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "chairs".* FROM "chairs" WHERE "chairs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 106ms (ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)


  
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Chair with 'id'=undefined):`

Comment: can you specify the method in which it is raising this issue @Thatdude

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180877/discussion-between-sumanth-madishetty-and-that-dude).

Comment: @Thatdude Please check if all the order items are stored to db as expected ot not

Comment: nope @Sumanth Madishetty nothing is getting stored, i checked it

Comment: Can you check why its not getting stored i mean what are the attributess that are need for the record to get saved properly and in which table is this issue comming and can you explain the flow clearly in the chat link specified above

Comment: Why are you keeping null false only for chair in order items table adn add rescue block in the method so that you will get to know if any error occured and what error has occured in the method @Thatdude

Comment: Hey @Sumanth Madishetty, i know you have helped too much, but am new can you please look at my code for once
here is the github link: https://github.com/ahmedreza80/ddtest

Comment: It takes a lot of time to go through that codee...can u explain the flow of code and where you are facing the issue

Comment: What ever the code that is in git hub works fine for you????are you facing issues while adding bookcabinet to your code am i right?

Comment: the problem right now is everything works fine if i delete the bookcabinet bit and work with a single product but as i add the bookcabinet in createorderitem migration, it stops storing the data

Comment: Why are you adding null false in the migration for chair item

Comment: Its throwing the error because you have kept chair_id as must inorder to create orde item and you are not passing the chair id

Comment: And it is highly recommended to add standard rescue block in your methods so that you can know what the exact error is and where it is